# How to index a log file in elastic search

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstasher gem to collect logs in logstash_development.log.This file(logstash_deveopment.log) has all the logs in json format.I am trying to index al those logs in elasticsearch by using below command,

```
curl -XPOST' http://localhost:9200/jeeva' -d  @/home/shakthi/work/vs_web/spree_main/log/logstash_development.log
```

But I get the following result {"acknowledged":true}. My logs are not indexed properly.How to index a log file in elastic search?

Comment: Your command will post the whole log files contents as a single document. I'm pretty sure that isn't what you want. I suggest you use Logstash to read the file line by line and pass the resulting log messages to Elasticsearch.

Comment: First of all should it be in JSON format only ? how about the usual logs that we get from different environments. Should we convert them to JSON first ?